# Добавление рандомного элемента из массива строк в Dictionary на C#

Tags: c#, коллекции, словари

В общем, надо добавить факультеты в словарь Dictionary <string,Person> faculty, ключ-строка, значение-человек(студент или преподаватель).
 Для выбора названий факультета есть массив строк faculties, откуда в цикле for добавляется рандомно выбранный элемент из faculties в качестве ключа. 
 Беда в том, что добавив несколько элементов происходит зацикливание. Ну допустим, он выбирает элемент "ФЭМБИ", добавляет его, потом добавляет следующий, но в итоге у программы не остается выбора кроме как добавить уже добавленный ключ, он опять выбирает "ФЭМБИ", происходит эксепшн, там происходит откат на шаг назад, он снова пытается добавить "ФЭМБИ", снова уходит в эксепшн...... 
    Понятно, что чем больше названий факультетов для выбора, тем меньше вероятности, что произойдет зацикливание, но хотелось бы как то заставить программу пахать с небольшим количеством вариантов для выбора) Можно как-то "обмануть" словарь чтобы он добавлял уже добавленные ключи?

```
    using laba10;
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;


namespace laba14
{
 class Program
  {
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {            
        Dictionary<string, Person> faculty = new Dictionary<string, Person>();

        List<Dictionary<string, Person>> university = new List<Dictionary<string, Person>>();
        Random rand = new Random();

        string[] faculties = {"ФЭМБИ", "ФГиГИТ", "МИЭФ", "МИРЭК", "ФДП"};

        Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.DarkYellow;
        Console.WriteLine("\nДобавление элементов в коллекцию:");
        Console.ResetColor();

        Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.DarkYellow;
        Console.WriteLine("\nВведите количество элементов для добавления:\n");
        Console.ResetColor();
        int size;
        bool ok = int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out size);

        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
        {
            try
            {
                //чтобы половина была студентов, половина преподавателей
                if (i % 2 == 0)
                {
                    faculty.Add(faculties[rand.Next(faculties.Length)], new Student());
                    
                }
                else
                {
                    faculty.Add(faculties[rand.Next(faculties.Length)], new Teacher());
                }
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                i--;
            }
        }
        foreach (var v in faculty.Keys)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"{v}  |   {faculty[v]}");
        }
    }
}
}
```

Вот в этой строчке добавление чтобы не искать в коде:

```
faculty.Add(faculties[rand.Next(faculties.Length)], new Student());
```

Answer (score 0):

В общем я просто поменяла ключ-значение местами, теперь на месте ключа объект Person (имя+фамилия+возраст), поэтому уникальность повышается в разы, 100,000 элементов из 36 фамилий+36 имен+ возраста в диапазоне от 18 до 80 формирует.  Изменились строчки:

```
          Dictionary< Person,string> faculty = new Dictionary< Person,string>();
         List<Dictionary< Person,string>> university = new List<Dictionary< Person,string>>();

               //чтобы половина была студентов, половина преподавателей
                if (i % 2 == 0)
                {
                    faculty.Add(new Student(),faculties[rand.Next(faculties.Length)]);
                    
                }
                else
                {
                    faculty.Add(new Teacher(), faculties[rand.Next(faculties.Length)]);
                }
```

Comment: Контроль уникальности у вас не по содержимому объекта, а по экземпляру, попробуйте добавить 2 раза одинакового `new Student()`, то есть сколько угодно раз вы сможете это сделать, потому что каждый раз добавляется уникальный объект, и содержимое не имеет никакого значения, даже если все содержимое у двух объектов будет идентично. Вы пока не поняли, как это работает, попытайтесь понять. Еще попробуйте достать элемент из словаря, у вас с большой вероятностью ничего не получится, потому что вам придется иметь ссылку на оригинальный экземпляр ключа. В общем, поиграйтесь, вас ждут сюрпризы.

Answer (score 0):

Все, отмена, я сделала ситуацию еще страшнее. Добавила класс отдельно для факультета, теперь все пашет как надо (до поры до времени)

```
    public class Faculty
{ 

    string Name { get; set; }
    Random rand = new Random();
    string[] faculties = { "ФЭМБИ", "ФГиГИТ", "МИЭФ", "МИРЭК", "ФДП", "ИСФ", "СГФ", "ТЭФ", "ФАИД", "ФАД", "ФКФН", "ЮФ", "ЗФ", "МИЭМ", "ФПЭ", "ИКТ", "ПМИ" };
   
    public Faculty()
    {
        Name = faculties[rand.Next(faculties.Length)];
    }
    public Faculty(string name)
    {
        Name = name;
    }
    public override string ToString()
    {
        return $"{Name}";
    }
}
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {            
        Dictionary<Faculty,Person> faculty = new Dictionary<Faculty, Person>();

        List<Dictionary<Faculty, Person>> university = 
            new List<Dictionary<Faculty, Person>>();

        Random rand = new Random();
        
        Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.DarkYellow;
        Console.WriteLine("\nДобавление элементов в коллекцию:");
        Console.ResetColor();

        Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.DarkYellow;
        Console.WriteLine("\nВведите количество элементов для добавления:\n");
        Console.ResetColor();
        int size;
        bool ok = int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out size);

        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
        {
            try
            {
                //чтобы половина была студентов, половина преподавателей
                if (i % 2 == 0)
                {
                    faculty.Add(new Faculty(), new Student());
                }
                else
                {
                    faculty.Add(new Faculty(), new Teacher());
                }
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                i--;
            }
        }
        foreach (var v in faculty.Keys)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"{v}  |   {faculty[v]}");
        }
}
```